# How to call a method in render instead of componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

I want to avoid componentDidUpdate lifecycle and want to call a method within render. Since I am not loading data in this component I want to get rid of componentDidUpdate.

Below is the code,

```
export default class child extends React.Component {
    state = {
        query: '',
        data: null,
    };
    empty_id = 0xffffffff;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.set_open_data();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if (prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
            this.set_data();
       }
    }

    set_data = () => {
        if (!this.props.info) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.props.id === this.empty_id) {
            this.setState({data: null});
            return;
        }

        let data = {
            info: [],
            values: [],
        };
        const info = this.props.info;
        for (let i=0, ii=info.length; i < ii; i++) {
            if (info[i].meshes.includes(this.props.id)) {
                const info = info[i].info;
                const values = info[i].values;
                data = {
                    info: typeof info === 'string' ? info.split('\r\n') : [],
                    values: values ? values : [],
                };
                break;
            }
        }
        this.setState({data: this.filter_data(data, this.state.query)});
      };
      render = () => {
          /* i want to call set_data here but should not sure of when to be 
         called meaning condition like in componentdidupdate method*/
         this.set_data();};}
```

Could someone help me solve this? Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you set the state from within the render function (or within `componentDidUpdate`), your component will re-render because you called `setState`. This in turn calls the render function again which calls `setState` again leaving you with an infinite loop of renders. Why do you want to re-set data during the render function or after updating.

Comment: You should explain what you want to achieve.. Anyways, @ApplePearPerson is quite right, but using `setState()` in `componentDidUpdate()` it's ok: you just need to put the `setState()` into a condition (which, of course, must not take always, otherwise you enter into an infinite loop).

Comment: @Matteo Gesmundo how can i rewrite set_data method such that it doesn't use setState for data to use this set_data method in render method? thanks.

Comment: @stackoverflow_user Honestly, I didn't understand your question >_> Let me say this (maybe it can help you): inside `render()` it's ok calling function that kinda builds data starting from the current state. Instead, if you need to change the state of the Component if the current state fulfill some condition, you need to use `setState()` inside the `componentDidUpdate()` method